Flutter hide next and previous button in lockscreen
I dont need the previous and next button in lockscreen using just_audio_background
after much searching and trying i come to understand that i need playbackstate
playbackState.add(PlaybackState(
      controls: [
        //MediaControl.play, // Control pour démarrer la lecture
       MediaControl.pause, // Control pour mettre en pause
        MediaControl.stop,  // Control pour arrêter
      ],
      playing: false,
      processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready,
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1],
    )

but the buttons still always in the lockscreen, any solution please.
